# if statement within __init__ python class is not working

Tags: python, class, pytorch

This is maybe a really dumb question, but I am pretty frustrated, so bear with me. I am writing a class to perform neural net analysis using pytorch, and I have some "if" statements within the init definition.

```
class RBM(nn.Module):
    '''
    This class defines all the functions needed for an BinaryRBN model
    where the visible and hidden units are both considered binary
    '''

    def __init__(self,
                visible_units=256,
                hidden_units = 64,
                k=2,
                learning_rate=1e-5,
                learning_rate_decay = False,
                xavier_init = False,
                increase_to_cd_k = False,
                use_gpu = False
                ):

        super(RBM,self).__init__()
        self.desc = "RBM"

        self.visible_units = visible_units
        self.hidden_units = hidden_units
        self.k = k
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.learning_rate_decay = learning_rate_decay
        self.xavier_init = xavier_init
        self.increase_to_cd_k = increase_to_cd_k
        self.use_gpu = use_gpu
        self.batch_size = 16


        # Initialization
        if not self.xavier_init:
            print("I am here")
            self.W = torch.randn(self.visible_units,self.hidden_units) * 0.01 #weights
        else:
            self.xavier_value = torch.sqrt(torch.FloatTensor([1.0 / 
                                                              (self.visible_units + self.hidden_units)]))
            self.W = -self.xavier_value + torch.rand(self.visible_units, 
                                                     self.hidden_units) * (2 * self.xavier_value)
        self.h_bias = torch.zeros(self.hidden_units) #hidden layer bias
        self.v_bias = torch.zeros(self.visible_units) #visible layer bias
        
        if self.use_gpu:
            self.W = self.W.cuda()
            self.v_bias = self.v_bias.cuda()
            self.h_bias = self.h_bias.cuda()
            if self.xavier_init:
                self.xavier_value = self.xavier_value.cuda()
```

This class fails whenever I specify `use_gpu=True`, but is fine if I specify `use_gpu=False`. For example:

```
 rbm = RBM(use_gpu=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/Deep-Belief-Network-pytorch-master/RBM.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.v_bias = self.v_bias.cuda()
  File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 585, in __getattr__
    type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'RBM' object has no attribute 'xavier_value'
```

So the specific error I'm getting has to do with the variable `self.xavier_value`, but this variable should never get called given the `if self.xavier_init` call. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: But, if `xavier_init` is `False`, but `use_gpu` is True, then you will access `self.xavier_value.cuda()`.

Comment: What's the connection between DBN (the class you're creating an instance of) and RBM (the class whose definition you're showing us)?

Comment: @quamrana, I'm not sure why... `if self.use_gpu` takes me inside that statement, then `if self.xavier_init` should take me to `self.xavier_value`. If `self.xavier_init` is `False`, then `self.xavier_value` should never be initiated.

Comment: @FrankYellin, yeah my apologies. DBN is calling RBM a few times, to create a deep belief network.

Comment: Yes, if `xavier_init` is `False`, then there is no `self.xavier_value`. But, then, if `use_gpu` is True, then you access `self.xavier_value.cuda()`, when there is no `self.xavier_value`.

Comment: @quamrana, how? `if self.xaview_init` (given that `self.xaview_init=False`) should prevent me from entering in the statement that tries to use `self.xaview_value`

Comment: Ok. Enough of that. show us the missing code. Your error traceback (Thanks for that, you wouldn't believe the number of posters who don't supply one) shows the error is in `RBM.py` on line 64

Comment: I edited the question to show a single call to `RBM(use_gpu=1)`, since the DBN thing was probably confusing (my apologies). This is the entirety of the `def __init__` function.

Comment: Also, `RBM.py` consists of this `__init__` function plus a couple of other functions

Comment: @quamrana, what missing code are you talking about?

Comment: Its ok, you posted it. Sorry, I still can’t work out why the line: self.v_bias = self.v_bias.cuda() has anything to do with the error.

Comment: This is not the whole initialization code is it? could you post the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

```py
class RBM(nn.Module):
    '''
    This class defines all the functions needed for an BinaryRBN model
    where the visible and hidden units are both considered binary
    '''

    def __init__(self,
                visible_units=256,
                hidden_units = 64,
                k=2,
                learning_rate=1e-5,
                learning_rate_decay = False,
                xavier_init = False, # By default xavier_init is false
                increase_to_cd_k = False,
                use_gpu = False
                ):

        super(RBM,self).__init__()
        self.desc = "RBM"

        self.visible_units = visible_units
        self.hidden_units = hidden_units
        self.k = k
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.learning_rate_decay = learning_rate_decay
        self.xavier_init = xavier_init
        self.increase_to_cd_k = increase_to_cd_k
        self.use_gpu = use_gpu
        self.batch_size = 16


        # Initialization
        if self.xavier_init: # If xavier_init is true
            self.xavier_value = torch.sqrt(torch.FloatTensor([1.0 / 
                                                              (self.visible_units + self.hidden_units)]))
            self.W = -self.xavier_value + torch.rand(self.visible_units, 
                                                     self.hidden_units) * (2 * self.xavier_value)
        else: # if xavier_init is false
            print("I am here")
            self.W = torch.randn(self.visible_units,self.hidden_units) * 0.01 #weights
        self.h_bias = torch.zeros(self.hidden_units) #hidden layer bias
        self.v_bias = torch.zeros(self.visible_units) #visible layer bias
        
        if self.use_gpu:
            self.W = self.W.cuda()
            self.v_bias = self.v_bias.cuda()
            self.h_bias = self.h_bias.cuda()
            if self.xavier_init: # If xavier_init is true
                self.xavier_value = self.xavier_value.cuda()
```